# How do I write a Python unit test for a recursive function with mocking?

Tags: python, unit-testing, recursion, mocking, python-unittest

I am new to Python. This is my code:

```py
import requests

def abc(url, number_of_retry=2):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, timeout=30)
    except Exception as ex:
        if number_of_retry != 0:
            return abc(url, number_of_retry-1)
        else:
            raise ex
    return response.status_code
```

In my case I want to write a test case where at the time of first method call we get an exception. So that the code in the catch block is executed, from where we call the same method recursively and in this case we will have the successful call and get a mock response.

Output:

1. retry count of `requests.get` which will be 2
2. `status_code` we supplied from mock object which will be `200`.

I tried this at my end:

```py
from unittest import mock

...

@mock.patch('requests.get')
def test_abc(self, get_mock):
    get_mock.side_effect = Exception
    with self.assertRaises(Exception):
         myclass.abc(url)
    self.assertEqual(get_mock.call_count, 3)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want help with. (btw I would expect an iterative solution to be easier to write.)

Comment: You may want to use the version of `side_effect` that takes a list to provide an exception followed by a valid (mocked) response.

Comment: `abc` should not be recursive in the first place. Use a loop.

Comment: @chepner Why? I mean, I would make it iterative too, but that is just a personal preference. I see no big issue with the recursive approach here. So long as you don't make the call stack too deep (i.e. hundreds of retries).

Comment: That's the point: why use a design with an arbitrary constraint when a simple loop is available?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, [`Mock.side_effect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect) allows you to define an **iterable** of objects. Each call of the mock will then yield the next item from that iterable and if that item is an exception, raise it, and return it otherwise.

This allows you to define behavior for your mock object such as *"raise exception `E` on the first call, but return object `X` on the second"*.

Assuming this is your function:

```py
import requests


def abc(url: str, number_of_retry: int = 2) -> int:
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, timeout=30)
    except Exception as ex:
        if number_of_retry != 0:
            return abc(url, number_of_retry - 1)
        else:
            raise ex
    return response.status_code
```

You can write a test for it like this: (Longer than necessary, just for illustrative purposes.)

```py
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, call, patch


class MyTest(TestCase):
    @patch("requests.get")
    def test_abc(self, mock_get: MagicMock) -> None:
        fake_url = "foo/bar"
        expected_output = 200
        mock_response = MagicMock(status_code=200)
        desired_effects = [
            RuntimeError("Not yet..."),
            ValueError("Still bad..."),
            TimeoutError("Almost there..."),
            mock_response,
        ]
        mock_get.side_effect = desired_effects
        with self.assertRaises(RuntimeError):
            abc(fake_url, number_of_retry=0)  # first `get` call
        with self.assertRaises(TimeoutError):
            abc(fake_url, number_of_retry=1)  # second and third `get` call
        output = abc(fake_url, number_of_retry=0)  # fourth `get` call
        self.assertEqual(expected_output, output)
        self.assertListEqual(
            4 * [call(fake_url, timeout=30)],
            mock_get.call_args_list,
        )

        # Reset:
        mock_get.reset_mock()
        mock_get.side_effect = desired_effects
        output = abc(fake_url, number_of_retry=3)  # four `get` calls in total
        self.assertEqual(expected_output, output)
        self.assertListEqual(
            4 * [call(fake_url, timeout=30)],
            mock_get.call_args_list,
        )
```

As you can see, the iterator created from `side_effect` is consumed in three "separate test steps" first: No retries yields a `RuntimeError`; then with one retry we get a `ValueError` first, but swallow it and ultimately end up with the `TimeoutError`; and finally we receive the fake response object, from which we return the status code.

Just to demonstrate, I then reset the mock object and the `side_effect` iterator and called `abc` again with 3 retries, which produced the expected output again.

You can also see that we can track exactly how often and with what arguments our mocked `get` function was called via [`Mock.call_args_list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_args_list).